# Jersey client side strategy to test main page after login

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey to create a web application. Currently there are two pages: login and main page. When user inputs correct username and password, the login page gets redirected into main page (otherwise the warning is presented in a pop up window, with no redirection).

In the main page, certain content is retrieved from the server and updated on the page.

Since there is no of username and password on the main page, how can I write client side code to varify whether the correct content is rendered to the main page, after the user is logged in successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use an HTML parsing library, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Here's a complete example, using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). You can run it just like any other unit test

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import org.junit.Test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

public class HtmlParserTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("login")
    public static class LoginController {

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        public String doLogin(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
            boolean valid = false;
            valid = "user".equals(formParams.getFirst("username"));
            valid = "pass".equals(formParams.getFirst("password"));

            String message = valid ? "You Win!" : "You Lose!";
            String html
                    = "<html>\n"
                    + "    <body>\n"
                    + "        <h1 id=\"message\">" + message + "</h1>\n"
                    + "    </bod;y>\n"
                    + "</html>";
            return html;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(LoginController.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void youWinMessageWithValidCredentials() {
        String message = handleRequest("pass");
        assertEquals("You Win!", message);
    }

    @Test
    public void youLoseMessageWithBadCredentials() {
        String message = handleRequest("wrong");
        assertEquals("You Lose!", message);
    }

    private String handleRequest(String password) {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.param("username", "user");
        form.param("password", password);
        String html = target("login").request()
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .post(Entity.form(form), String.class);
        return getMessageContent(html);
    }

    /* jsoup code */
    private String getMessageContent(String html) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element messageElem = document.getElementById("message");
        return messageElem.text();
    }
}
```

Here are the dependencies for the test

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <scope>${jersey2.version}</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/features/) Framework for such kind of tests. Besides the Arquillian Core lot's of extensions are available.
For your use case I would use the [Arquillian Drone Extension](http://arquillian.org/modules/drone-extension/) and the [REST Extension](http://arquillian.org/modules/rest-extension/) (if you are using restful services after the login).
Arquillian Drone allows you to write client side tests for web sites and with the rest extension restful webservices can be tested.

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone?_sscc=t) is an example for testing a login page with Arquillian Drone.